# How to display the line number for laravel errors on Windows cli

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-5, command-prompt

I have two machines on Windows, when running a php script on the command prompt one machine shows the line number of any errors, the other spits out the error message without a line number. In the browser both are showing line numbers.

Is there a setting somewhere I need to enable to get line numbers shown in command prompt?

The machine that shows the line number is on the Windows Insider Fast Ring so perhaps there have been some changes there?

**UPDATED**

Here are some more findings. I am running a Laravel artisan command, this is working on a clean install of Laravel.

Php 7 and 7.1
Adding an error to the actual artisan file will show the line number of the error. Adding an error in various files will show their line number. At some point though line numbers are not shown for errors - I haven’t worked out exactly what is turning this off.

Php 5.6
Adding an error anywhere in the code shows the line number of the error.

It seems to be a combination of the php version and something when Laravel runs. I’ve tried about 10 versions of php, both x86, x64, thread safe and non-thread safe but it seems no version of php 7 will show line numbers of errors on Window for artisan commands.

Comment: Strange, do you use the same PHP version on both machines?

Comment: Very strange indeed. I've seen people complain about the line numbers being off or wrong, but never about not seeing any line numbers at all. Not even once while doing some intensive searching with Google.

Comment: @FabianH. only the non-working machine in front of me, it was on 7.0.6 (ZendServer) now on 7.0.15 after an upgrade this morning and I don’t get any error messages on the command line at all now!
php.ini: error_reporting=E_ALL display_errors=On

Comment: Okay, the lack of errors since updating php is project specific, other projects now show errors with a line number. The weird thing is another developer is working on this project and does get errors.

Comment: Check if those values are set with `phpInfo()` in your console. If not, check if the ini you're editing is loaded and not overwritten `php --ini`. Do you use Windows or Linux OS?

Comment: @FabianH.I’m on Windows. I think it’s the code. I’m making an Laravel package. If I test other code I get errors shown so it must be something in this package causing the problem even though the other developer can see them and I could with the older version of php excluding line numbers. Errors are logged to the laravel.log

Comment: Yes, Laravel reroutes all PHP errors with `set_error_handler()`